# Arrow and Lexical Scope in JS

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions, lexical-scope

Given the following code:

```
const outter = {
  inner: {
    laughter: "hahaha",
    laugh: () => {
      console.log(this) //`this` is window
    }
  }
}

const x = {
  test: function () {
    const laugh = outter.inner.laugh
    console.log(this) //`this` is x
    laugh()
  }
}

x.test()
```

I would expect the `this` inside of the `laugh` method to be equal to `x` - because we're invoking `laugh` from `x`

In the scope where we invoke `laugh`, `this` *is* equal to `x` - so it's strange that `this` changes in the arrow method, which should follow lexical scope.

(note, even if we change `laugh` to a normal function, non-arrow, `this` is still `Window` - but that makes sense)

Can anyone explain why `this` inside of `laugh` is `Window`?

Thanks

Comment: `this` in `inner.outer.laugh` has context of `window` because it's an arrow function. When you assign the value of `laugh` to `outer.inner.laugh` and then call it, you're not giving it a new context - just executing it

Comment: The value of `this` in an arrow function depends on were it is *defined*, not where it's called.

Comment: @DennisVash yes it does, it just works differently. see this example:  https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Comment: @Pointy what do you mean where it is defined? Where what is defined? We don't define `this`..?

Comment: Where the arrow function is defined. That's what "lexical context" means.

Comment: @Pointy ok thanks for the clarification, but in this case.. the arrow function is defined inside of `inner`, which is in `outter` - neither of which is `Window`. Feel like i'm missing something basic here

Comment: *Lexical* scope means that it keeps (like a closure) the `this` value from the scope where it is *defined*, not that from where it is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According Jason Orendorff, the guy who implemented arrow functions for Firefox, wrote the following ([here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)):

> **Arrow functions do not have their own this value.** The value of `this` inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope.

The arrow function is not assigned when invoked, rather, when it's defined.

In your example, the arrow function of the `laugh` property will be bound to the `this` in the scope it was defined in, which in your example is `window`.

#### Update

The OP remarked in the comments that since the arrow function is found inside an inner property of the `outter` [sic] object, it should pick up the scope of that object. Superficially, this is the way *it should be*.

The caveat is that when creating objects, JS has to assign the property values from the inside out. In other words, the `inner` object literal is created first, at a time when the context of `outter` *doesn't even exist yet!*. And, therefore, since arrow functions get bound at the time of creation, the function for the `outter.inner.laugh` method is being bound with the context that it is found in; at the time of *creating* `outter.inner`, that would be `window`.

Comment: but the arrow function is defined inside of the object `outter` - isn't that its scope?

Comment: See the update, I tried to explain where the gap happens between what you should expect and what actually happens.

Comment: Nice!  The context question with object literals is one of those things that tend to bite you in JS, even as a seasoned coder. Your question had a pretty good twist to it 

Comment: haha thanks, I knew there was something else I was missing :p nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

### Arrow Functions:

- Do not have `this`.
- Do not have `arguments`.
- Can’t be called with `new`.
- They also don’t have `super`.

### Arrow functions have no “this”

If `this` is accessed, it is taken from the outside.

```
const outter = {
  inner: {
    laughter: "hahaha",
    laugh: () => {
      console.log(this) // the outer `this` is window.
    }
  }
}
```

Read more [here](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions).

Comment: ok, what is the "outside" of `laugh`? it's `outter` - what am I missing here?